# Changing magento sales PDF invoice value

Tags: magento, pdf

Today I am trying to change the tax value in Magento pdf sales invoice. Actually I want to put static tax amount in it like I want 20% of product amount that will be Tax and I want to minus Tax amount from product cost.

For example:
Product cost is 100 and 20% of product price will be 20 so I want to display 20 under Tax and the rest cost (80) as product price only in invoice not on website because on the website product price will be 100 because that is including taxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for printable invoice, that's located in:

```
app/design/frontend/{theme-package}/{your-theme}/template/page/print.phtml
```

or if your theme doesn't have this file, you have to rewrite it from base theme in:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/print.phtml
```